# a close button inside tab button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a HTML button as a tab and a close icon inside my button(< i > element) as a close button, when I click on the tab the "activateTab" action dispatches and when I click on the close icon inside my button "deactivateFile" and "removeTab" actions dispatch

My problem is clicking on close icon dispatches three actions ("activateTab" and "deactivateFile" and "removeTab") instead of two because my close icon is inside the button.

How can I dispatch only two actions when I click on the close button (tabs should have a close button in my project)
should I edit my HTML/CSS? or only my reducer?

Tab component:

```
function NewTab(props) {
return (
    <> 
        <button 
            className={`new-tab ${props.isActive ? 'selected-tab' : ''}` } 
            onClick={() => {
                //dispatch actions when tab is clicked
                props.activateTab(props.id)
            }}
            >
            <i className="tab-icon far fa-file"></i>
            {props.name}
            <i onClick={() => 
                {
                    //dispatch actions when close button is clicked
                    props.deactivateFile(props.id)
                    props.removeTab(props.id)
                }} 
                className="fas fa-times close-btn" >
            </i>
        </button>    
    </>
)
}
```

Tab preview:

[my tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ncx8.png)

Comment: _“should I edit my HTML/CSS?”_ - yes, absolutely. The HTML first of all. _“I have a HTML button as a tab and a close icon inside my button”_ - the usability of such a construct is likely to be terrible. HTML forbids nesting “interactive” elements for good reason. You only added the interactivity to the `i` element via JS here, but the result is likely still the same - a usability catastrophe for anyone using assistive technologies. I’m guessing not even focusing this close button via keyboard navigation is going to work here.

Comment: Thank you for review. What solution do you suggest for my problem? how can I create a tab with close button?

Comment: This should be a second button, to keep halfway proper semantics and functionality. If you want to put one “inside” the other regarding what it _looks like_, then wrap them both into a container element, so that you can absolutely position one above the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop propagating an event by `event.stopPropagation()`

```
onClick={(event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```

You really shouldn't have a remove tab functionality inside a new tab button though.

Answer (score 0):

Using click event in both parent and child element can triggered issue. so its better to separate them and bind it with its corresponding function or events.

Comment: You are right. I edited my HTML and I added two button instead one.